# Symfony 4 registration form second submit "There is already an active transaction"

Tags: php, symfony, registration

I have created a user registry just as in the documentation.
At some point later I wanted to add the CSRF. Since then it does not work properly anymore. I have the package installed and removed.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

```
composer require security-csrf
composer remove security-csrf
rm -rf vendor
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

That did not help.

When I fill out the form and submit. If the user is saved.
I do a second time, I get the error message below.

Only when I remove the cookie "PHPSESSID" in the browser, then I can send the form once again. After that is the same problem again.

```
PDOException:
There is already an active transaction

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:1249
  at PDO->beginTransaction()
     (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:1249)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->beginTransaction()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:376)
  at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(null)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:358)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
     (src/Controller/RegistrationController.php:40)
  at App\Controller\RegistrationController->registerAction(object(Request), object(UserPasswordEncoder))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

I tried to debug that. The transaction was activated somewhere, then not again. I can not find the problem. Is anyone able to help me?

symfony/config/services.yaml

```
services:
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - !service { class: PDO, factory: 'database_connection:getWrappedConnection' }
            - { db_table: session, db_username: username, db_password: password }
```

Comment: Sometimes you just have to make a new form without forms.
Delete the cookie, wait a few days. And then it works again... Uh what? Problem is fixed for the time being. The cause but in vain.

Comment: And sometimes the error comes again...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've had this same issue recently, and for me it was down to using `PDOSessionHandler` along with sharing the Doctrine connection with `getWrappedConnection`.

In your `services.yaml` change your `PdoSessionHandler` service definition

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
    arguments:
        - !service { class: PDO, factory: 'database_connection:getWrappedConnection' }
        - { lock_mode: 1 }`
```

I.e. just add the lock_mode argument in addition. That "fixed" it for me, though I'm looking in more depth as to why as it would be better to use LOCK_TRANSACTIONAL rather than LOCK_ADVISORY.

Comment: Mark your comment helped and saved me alot of time. Really appreciate it. Just wondering how were you able to pinpoint the issue. I tried to debug it for a bit but seemed to get no where.